Different approaches to the Daniell Integral
I've got a a question about Daniell-integration theory. There is a standard way of construction the Daniell-integral in two steps (for example described in Taylor or Royden). In the last step you define a function to be integrable if the lower and the upper integrals constructed previously are equal. That's the classical way of constructing the Daniell-integral as suggested by Daniell.
Another way is described for example in Riesz/Nagy or Shilov where the first step of the construction is almost (you have to be careful with the boundness of the integral sequences) the same. But the last step is different: You define a function to be integrable if it can be represented as the difference of two functions which are integrable in the sense of the first step of the construction.
The second approach seems easier to me for proving theorems.
My question is if someone knows any literature which discusses the equivalence of these two approaches. Or maybe there is a more general respresentation theorem behind this.
Thank you for your help!

None of those textbooks have a purely Daniell approach. The book Bichteller, K., integration: A functional approach, Birkhauser, 1997 developes the whole theory with Daniell means on Stone lattices and linear rings. The motivation starts from Riemann integration, the constriction of a mean via Daniell upper and lower integral and then the extension. Measure theory follows as a bioproduct of this theory. Stromberg, Harmonic Analysis, Springer, also develops the Daniell integral in a similar fashion.

Thank you, that's true. But my initial question adresses more the statement at the end of this text (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniell_integral) where the equivalence of the two approaches is claimed.
